# How to read a input file in an array in c++

Tags: c++, string, file-io

I'm trying to store hexadecimal values into some form of an array from a file then change those numbers to binary. So far the program I wrote is only collects the last value. The file looks something like this. note(a 1 or 0 is before each hex value)

```
1   408ed4
0   10019d94
0   408ed8
1   10019d88
0   408edc
0   1001322
```

My code is #include

```
#include <fstream> 
#include <string> 
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <bitset>
#include <sstream>
#define MAX_ADDRESSES 1000000
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    //Declare variables
    int szL1 = atoi(argv[2]);
    int szL2 = atoi(argv[4]);
    string type = argv[6]; //Determines the type of cache
    //string fileN = argv[7];
    int info, i = 1, j = 1; //info is what is read in, i & j are testing variables
    string *rd_add = new string[MAX_ADDRESSES]; //set the max string length for what's read
    string *wrt_add = new string[MAX_ADDRESSES]; //set the max string length for what's written

    int total = 0; //total # of reads/writes
    int rds = 0; //base # of reads
    int wrt = 0; //base # of writes

    int array_size = 1001024;
    char *array = new char[array_size];
    int position = 0;

    ifstream fin("big_trace.txt");//open big trace file********
    if (fin.is_open()){
        cout << "File opened successfully" << endl;

        while (!fin.eof() && position < array_size){
            fin.get(array[position]);
            position++;
        }
        array[position - 1] = '\0';
        for (int x = 0; array[x] != '\0'; i++){
            cout << array[i];
        }


    }
    else{
        cout << "File could not be opened" << endl;

    }


    //check for a power of 2 for szL1
    while (1)
    {
        if (i == szL1)
            break;

        //Error Message
        else if (i > szL1)
        {
            cout << "Error. sizeL1 must be a power of 2. Please try again." << endl << endl;
            return 0;
        }

        i *= 2;
    }

    //cout << "size1 " << szL1 << endl;
    //check for a power of 2 for szL2
    while (1)
    {
        if (j == szL2)
            break;
        //Error
        else if (j > szL2)
        {
            cout << "Error. sizeL2 must be a power of 2. Please try again." << endl << endl;
            return 0;
        }

        j *= 2;
    }
    //cout << "size2 " << szL2 << endl;
    //Check to see if szL2 is larger than szL1
    if (szL2 <= szL1)
    {
        cout << "Error. sizeL2 must be larger than sizeL1. Please try again." << endl << endl;
        return 0;
    }


    //Read file contents*****
    while (cin >> info)    //check this part
    {
        //If it is a 1, increment read files
        if (info == 1)
        {
            cin >> rd_add[i++];
            rds++;
        }
        else if (info == 0)
        {
            cin >> wrt_add[j++];
            wrt++;
        }
        else
        {
            continue;
        }

    }

    total = rds + wrt;

    //Print the arguments read
    cout << endl << "Input Parameters read:" << endl;
    cout << "SizeL1: " << szL1 << endl;
    cout << "SizeL2: " << szL2 << endl;
    cout << "Type: " << type << endl;

    //Print file stats
    cout << endl << "Memory References Read from File" << endl;
    cout << "Total: " << total << endl;
    cout << rds << " Reads" << endl;
    cout << wrt << " Writes" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get only the hexadecimal values in a vector and your file is as you said you can just do it as below:

```
String hexValue, dummy;

Vector<String> hexValueVector;

ifstream fin("big_trace.txt");//open big trace file********

if (fin.is_open()){
    cout << "File opened successfully" << endl;

    while (!fin.eof()){

      fin >> dummy >> hexValue;
      hexValueVector.push_back(hexValue);

....//your remaining code
```

Do not forget to include the Vector library.

```
#include <vector>
```

Hope this will help you.

EDITED:

if you need the dummy too you have just to put both values in a structure:

```
struct myStructure{

String dummy;     
String hexValue;
};
```

and instead of creating a vector of string you create a vector of myStructure:

```
Vector<myStructure> myStructureVector;
```

to fill your vector you have just to do this:

```
myStructure myStructure; 

if(fin.is_open()){
  ...
while (!fin.eof()){
fin >> myStructure.dummy >> myStructure.hexValue;

myStructureVector.push_back(myStructure);
```

If this solves your problem, please vote for the answer.

About Vector, it is a STL container, if you want more details about it check http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

Comment: This is good but I also need the 1 or 0 before it any idea how to get some spaces between them. Also can you explain what's going on I've never used vectors before.